# Change text of elements identified by dynamic XPath

Tags: xslt, xpath, xalan

I have an XML with 2 XML fragments, 1st one is a fragment where the new values must be applied (which can have pretty complex elements) like

```
... some static parents
<a:element1>
   <a:subelement tag="someString">
      <a:s1>a</a:s1>
   </a:subelement>
</a:element1>
<a:element2>b</a:element2>
<a:element3>c</a:element3>
... lots of other elements like the above ones
```

and 2nd fragment that has XPaths generated from the first XML and a new value, like

```
<field>
   <xpath>/Parent/element1/subelement[@tag="someString"]/s1</xpath>
   <newValue>1</newValue>
</field>
<field>
   <xpath>/Parent/element2</xpath>
   <newValue>2</newValue>
</field>
```

We might not have new values to apply for all the elements in the first fragment.

I'm struggling to make an XSLT transformation that should apply the new values to the places indicated by the XPaths.

The output should be:

```
... some static parents
<a:element1>
   <a:subelement tag="someString">
      <a:s1>1</a:s1>
   </a:subelement>
</a:element1>
<a:element2>2</a:element2>
... lots of other elements like the above ones
```

I have access to xalan:evaluate to evaluate the dynamic xpath. I'm trying different solutions, I will write them here when they will start to make sense.

Any ideas of approaches are well received. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Oki, I found out how, and I will write the answer here maybe someone sometime will need this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">

<!-- static parents -->
  <a:Root>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/a:Root/a:Parent" />
  </a:Root>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|*|text()">

<xsl:variable name="x" select="generate-id(../.)" />
<xsl:variable name="y" select="//field[generate-id(xalan:evaluate(xpath)) = $x]" />

<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="$y">
    <xsl:value-of select="$y/newValue" />
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*|text()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>

</xsl:template>
```

And to explain the transformation:
I'm writing down part that is static and then call apply-templates on the fragment I'm interested in, that has a liquid structure.

Then I'm using a slightly modified identity transformation that copies everything from source to target (starting from the **/a:Root/a:Parent** fragment), except when we position ourselves on the text I'm interested in changing.

The **text()** I'm interested in will have as parent **(../.)** the element referred by an xpath string found in the second fragment. Variable **x** means, in the context of the **when**, this element.

Variable **y** finds a **field** element that has as child an **xpath** element that if evaluated using **xalan** will refer to the same element that the **x** variable relates to.
Now I used **generate-id()** in order to compare the physical elements, otherwise it would have compared by the **toString** of the element (which is wrong). If variable **y** doesn't exist, it means that I have no **xpath** element for this element that could have changed, and I'm leaving it alone. If the **y** variable exists, I can get from it the **newValue** and I'm currently positioned on the element which text I want to update.